# Library for injecting JAWS and NVDA like functionality into the browser?

Tags: wai-aria

When JAWS or NVDA run the chrome browser takes on new functionality.  In particular, arrow keys act as clicks to expand/collapse properly decorated list items.  Is there a javascript library that will inject this same functionality when JAWS is not running?  This would be for a headless (and toothless) testing environment.

NOTE: NVDA provides a hint of the work involved in developing such a library [here](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/blob/release-2018.3.2/source/virtualBuffers/MSHTML.py).

Comment: can you explain your question a bit more?  i use both jaws and nvda and the (up/down) arrow keys just walk the accessibility tree (similar to the dom) but they don't act as "clicks".

Comment: I guess it's the focus capabilities I'm looking for (and anything else those tools add to the browser).  But I agree, the click handlers are already there but I can "click" them with a spacebar press when NVDA is running.  I'm looking for a js library that provides similar functionality.

Comment: your comment is still a little incorrect.  whether you can use the spacebar or enter to select an element such as a button, checkbox, or link has nothing to do with if a screen reader is running.  those same interactions will be there regardless.  however, a screen reader does give you different ways to navigate, such as pressing 'H' to go to the next heading, or 'T' to go to a table, or 'L' to go to a list, etc.  those features are pretty cool.  is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a library that would inject these shortcuts based on arai settings in the same way JAWS seems to be doing.  I found [this](https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/jaws-keyboard-shortcuts) for a complete? list of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI,

- JAWS shortcut keys are at https://doccenter.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/archives/training/jawskeystrokes.htm
- NVDA shortcut keys are at https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation.

After further clarification in the OP comments, I'm not aware of any libraries that inject these shortcut keys.  The shortcuts are single letter shortcuts.  They don't need a modifier.  For example, you press <kbd>H</kbd> to go to the next heading.  You don't need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or any other modifier.

Because they are single letter shortcuts, if you wanted them to work in your application when a screen reader is running, your entire app would have to have [`role="application"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#application), which is generally discouraged from an accessibility perspective.  But then having them work when a screen reader is running would be kind of weird because the shortcuts would already work *because* of the screen reader.

In general, it's a nice idea to try to surface these features to non-screen reader users, but since shortcut keys differ in some respects between JAWS and NVDA, it might be a little confusing if you tried this.

There are browser plugins that give you some of these features.  For example, to navigate by landmarks (JAWS calls them regions), you use <kbd>R</kbd> in JAWS and <kbd>D</kbd> in NVDA.  You can install the Landmarks plugin from http://matatk.agrip.org.uk/landmarks/.  It has its own set of keys to navigate by landmarks.